# How do I place neat ticks in arrow?

Tags: asymptote

I have this code for `testingarrowheads.asy`:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(1cm);
draw((0,0)--(2.82842,2.82842), arrow=Arrow(size=9), blue + linewidth(2.5pt));
path tick = (-0.1,0.1) -- (0,0);
draw(tick);
path tick = ((0.607,0.807) -- (0.707,0.707), linewidth(1.5pt));
draw(tick);
path tick = (1.314,1.514) -- (1.414,1.414);
draw(tick);
path tick = (2.021,2.221) -- (2.121,2.121);
draw(tick);
path tick = (2.728,2.928) -- (2.828,2.828);
draw(tick);
```

When running code with my cmd window with command:

```
asy testingarrowheads.asy
```

the following warning appears:

```
testingarrowheads.asy: 6.13: no matching function 'operator tuple(guide, pen)'
```

Also how do I make the 4 ticks placed in equal distances?

How do I make the two ticks at the vector sides actually coincide with the edges
of the vector. (At the moment the tick at the beginning of the vector doesn't match the edge of the left side of the vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 22/03/2017:** 
Since the two proposed solutions are limited to straight lines and the user has to specify the angle in order to have perpendicular mark, I have adapted a solution of `markers.asy`. Indeed with `markers.asy` it seems that only automatic rotated marks (with respect to the local tangent of the path) are available for midway (in arclength) between n+1 uniformly spaced marks. See examples in the Asymptote documention. It is possible to have marks on the point of the subdvision but they have a fixed orientation.

So I have adapted some routine to have automatic rotated marks placed on the points of the (equidistant, arclength) subdivision of the path.
Please find the following code

```
import markers;
unitsize(1cm);
pen pen1=blue+linewidth(2.5pt)+squarecap;
path p=(0,0)..(1,1)..(2,0);
draw(p, pen1,arrow=Arrow(size=9), TrueMargin(0pt,1.25pt));


markroutine markext_interval(int n=1, frame f, bool rotated=false)
{
    return new void(picture pic=currentpicture,frame mark, path g) {
        markuniform(centered=false,n,rotated)(pic,f,g);
    };
}

draw(p,marker(markext_interval(10,stickframe(1,size=4mm,space=0mm,angle=0,offset=I*2mm,p=linewidth(3bp)+yellow), rotated=true)),p=invisible);
```

and the picture

[image]

**Initial answer:**
Because `currentpen` is `roundcap` (see the Documentation) the first tick (at the beginning of the vector) doesn't match the edge of the left side of the vector. A possibility is to use `squarecap`. For the right part of the vector I do not have a perfect solution : play with `TrueMargin(real begin, real end)` which (see documentation) allows one to specify a margin directly in `PostScript` units, independent of the pen line width. You can add margin at the beginning and/or the end of the drawing vector.

Moreover in your code, line 6 is not correct. `linewidth` should be specified in `draw` command not in `path`.

I obtain with

```
  unitsize(1cm);
  pen p1=blue+linewidth(2.5pt)+squarecap;
  draw((0,0)--(2.82842,2.82842), p1,arrow=Arrow(size=9), TrueMargin(0pt,1.25pt));
  path tick = (-0.1,0.1) -- (0,0);
  draw(tick);
  path tick = ((0.607,0.807) -- (0.707,0.707));//, linewidth(1.5pt));
  draw(tick,linewidth(1.5pt));
  path tick = (1.314,1.514) -- (1.414,1.414);
  draw(tick);
  path tick = (2.021,2.221) -- (2.121,2.121);
  draw(tick);
  path tick = (2.728,2.928) -- (2.828,2.828);
  draw(tick);
```

the following picture

[image]

If you prefer `roundcap` try `TrueMargin(1.25pt,1.25pt)`.

**Edit 20/03/2017:** Asymptote contains some specific routines to put markers.

```
import markers;
path p=(0,0)--(2.82842,2.82842);
draw(p,marker(stickframe(1,size=4mm,angle=45,p=linewidth(1bp),offset=rotate(45)*I*2mm),markuniform(4)),p=invisible);
```

Notice that `angle=45` is to have perpendicular marks while `offset=rotate(45)*I*2mm` (`2mm` is `size/2`) is to have a well shift of the marks.
You can control with `p=linewidth(1bp)` the pen for your marks while `p=insivible` is the invisible pen (to not redraw the path `p`).

O.G.

Comment: thanks O.G. How do I make the ticks a bit longer?